# Find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ given $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = I_{x,x+1}(y)$ and $f_{X}(x) = I_{0,1}(x)$.

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = I_{x,x+1}(y)$ and $f_{X}(x) = I_{0,1}(x)$.

(a) Find $E[Y]$

$E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]]= E[E[x+1/2] = 1$ or

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \displaystyle\int_{x}^{x+1} (y)dy dx = 1$

(b) Find $Cov[X,Y]$

$E[Y] = E[Y] = 1$

$E[XY] = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \displaystyle\int_{x}^{x+1} (xy)dy dx = 7/12$

$Cov[X,Y]= 1/12$

(c) Find $P[X + Y < 1]$

Here I'm not sure but when I did my graphic my result was

$ 2 \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1/2} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{y} dx dy = 1/4$

Am I right??

(d) Find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$

I tried get the marginal but is not possible :( ,the main reason of this question is it

Thanks so much. Have a excellent day :)

Comment: Can you please write explicitly the marginal and the conditional densities from which you start? I am not totally sure that I interpret your notation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want us to verify (a) and (b) ?! If so, (a) looks correct, but in (b), E[X]=1/2, and assuming you did correctly E[XY] (I didn't verify that) you get Cov(X,Y)=1*1/2-7/12=-1/12

For (c), since (X,Y) are uniform on a parallelogram of area 1, P(X+Y<1) is the area of the region delimited into parallelogram by X+Y<1, which is a triangle indeed with area 1/4. I don't know how you arrived to that integral but it turns out with a correct result.

For (d), if you look at the graph, to get $f(x|y_{0})$, you have to split into two cases, $y_0$ from 0 to 1 and $y_0$ from 1 to 2. In the first case, x is moving *uniformly* on a segment between 0 and $y_0$ and in the second case , x is moving *uniformly* on a segment between $y_0-1$ and 1.

Comment: Thanks you so much :) , For (c) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%3Cy%3Cx%2B1+%2C+0+%3Cx%3C1  the triangule (0,0.5,0.5) (Vertexes) is the double of the triangule (0,1,0.5)

Comment: Sorry the triangule (0,1,0.5) is the double of the triangule (0,0.5,0.5) T have a typo

Comment: To be honest, I calculated $f(y_0)$ and $f(x|y_0)$ through integrals, and then I noticed it is uniform. I think we might have the following result: if $X$ is uniform, then for any other random variable $Y$, $X|y_0$ is uniform.