# Find $P[X + Y <1]$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that X and Y are jointly continuous random variables, $f_{X|Y}(x|y)= I_{(x,x+1)} \hspace{.2cm}(y)$, and $f_{X}(x)= I_{(0,1)}\hspace{.2cm}(x)$

(c) Find $P[X + Y <1]$.

my idea is to solve it this way

$P[X + Y <1]= P[Y <1-X]= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1-x} f_{X|Y}\hspace{.2cm}(x|y) f_{X}(x) \cdot dy dx$

but the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ and with that integral it doesn't come out

(Someone had already asked something similar, but I don't know how they get that integral 
$2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{0}^{y}  \cdot dx dy$, [Find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ given $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = I_{x,x+1}(y)$ and $f_{X}(x) = I_{0,1}(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481896/find-f-xyxy-given-f-yxyx-i-x-x1y-and-f-xx-i-0-1))

Comment: Why does the integral run from $x$ to $1-x$? What happens with the integration bounds when $x=0.75$?

Comment: The remark in your link about the parallelogram can be seen as a hint. You are left to show that each horizontal line on that parallelogram has the same mass by contradiction. So suppose $Y$ is not uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little error in your integral. The correct one is this:

$\mathbb{P}[X+Y<1]=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}dx \int_x^{1-x}dy$

Now it comes out....why? Do a draw and try to understand which is the support to integrate